# Vue mounted getBoundingClientRect().height but get 0

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a Vue components instance programmatically and I got some problems.

```vue
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var vm = new Vue({
        data:{
          mes:'hello vue'
        },
        template:'<div>{{mes}}</div>',
        mounted(){
          console.log(this.$el.getBoundingClientRect().height) // get 0
          this.$nextTick(()=>{
            console.log(this.$el.getBoundingClientRect().height) //get height
          })
        }
      }).$mount()
      document.body.appendChild(vm.$el)
    <script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question :

1. According to docs about the Vue lifecycle, the mounted hooks function should be called after *" Create `vm.$el` and replace 'el' with it "*. So I just thought the mounted hooks function should be called after document.body append `vm.$el` . While the fact is that it is called right after `vm.$mount()`
2. Why `this.$el.getBoundingClientRect().height` get 0 if it is not
   putted in vm.$nextTick function ?
3. As far as I know, `$nextTick` function created a microtask, while the browser UI render should be a macro task. So I don't know
   why we get the correct height if it is in $nextTick function.
   The DOM height should be calculated after it is putted in the page ( I
   mean `document.body.appendChild(vm.$el)`)?
   I thought microtask get handled before macro task, so even in `$nextTick` function we **shouldn't** get the right height. But it did. I wonder why.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted   Note this bit -> `If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use vm.$nextTick inside of mounted:`

Answer (score 2):

This part of the [`mounted` API docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) might be the explanation (emphasis mine):

> Called after the instance has been mounted, where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el. If the root instance is mounted to an in-document element, vm.$el will also be in-document when mounted is called.
>
> **Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use vm.$nextTick inside of mounted**

Regarding `$nextTick()`:

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update.

So either you have a child component or the DOM isn't rendered with you call `getBoundingClientRect()`

See also [Vue - is there any way to tie into render being finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49035674/vue-is-there-any-way-to-tie-into-render-being-finished)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `mount` you aren't telling it where to mount the `$el`. The `mounted` hook will be called before you get to the `document.body.appendChild(vm.$el)`, whereas the `$nextTick` will be after.

You shouldn't really be appending `$el` to the DOM yourself. Instead change your HTML to have a suitable target element:, e.g.:

```html
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
```

Here I've inserted a `<div>` as the first child of the `<body>`, immediately before your `<script>`, to ensure the element exists before the code inside `<script>` is run.

Then mount the Vue instance either using `el: '#app'` or by changing the `mount()` call to `mount('#app')`.